# update item total in java database

Tags: java, jdbc

I have an item in a database with a given quantity. I need that quantity to update by the amount i enter (qtyPurchased). For example, the item has 50 quantity, i then purchase 5, so the new quantity should return 55, however with the code I have it only returns 5.

This is what I have:

```
public void purchased(int qtyPurchased) throws SQLException {
    // TODO: Update the ProductsDB table's quantity for this
    // object's product code.
    try (Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(
                "UPDATE ProductsDB SET Quantity = ? WHERE Product_Code = ?")) {
            stat.setInt(1, qtyPurchased);
            stat.setString(2, productCode);
            stat.execute();
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried to do:

```
    stat.setInt(1, qty + qtyPurchased);
```

but always get an error. Please help! thanks

Comment: Why not increment the quantity in your SQL query? (`UPDATE ProductsDB SET Quantity = Quantity + ? WHERE Product_Code = ?`) I haven't test it but I think it should work

Comment: What's the error? Could you post the stacktrace? Where does 'qty' come from?

Comment: @Dorian's answer is correct.  Right now, you're always setting the quantity to the value of qtyPurchased instead of the current quantity *plus* qtyPurchased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increment your quantity and update the DB with that incremented value as below .

```
 public void purchased(int qtyPurchased) throws SQLException {
    // TODO: Update the ProductsDB table's quantity for this
    // object's product code.
    try (Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(
                (UPDATE ProductsDB SET Quantity = Quantity + ? WHERE Product_Code = ?)) {
            stat.setInt(1, qtyPurchased);
            stat.setString(2, productCode);
            stat.execute();
        }
    }

}
```

A another option is to get the quantity and store it in a variable then increment that and send that to the dB. This has the advantage of being able to use the new value stored in the var in other areas of you app.